# Implementing Search Contract - Incremental Search Behavior Possible?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I recently implemented the Search Contract in my formerly-known-as-Metro app, and I was suprised that typing into the Search Pane didn't yield incremental filtering behavior in my app's search results page.

Does anyone know whether this is possible? Is there some method that I need to override, or does this behavior not exist for Search?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can hook the [SuggestionRequeted event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.search.searchpane.suggestionsrequested.aspx) and supply search suggestions as the user is typing. See "Adding search suggestions" in this [quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868180%28v=win.10%29.aspx).  [This sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Search-app-contract-sample-118a92f5) also shows several different ways to give suggestions.

Per comment:  On the Search Results page (SearchResults.xaml.cs), add the filtering code to the Filter_SelectionChanged event handler and set the Results on DefaultViewModel to your filtered content.  An example of that [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/bc2932b7-78ce-4555-ab7c-b752d7422636).

Comment: Right, and the list of suggestions below the search text does change dynamically, but what I want is for the grid of items on the search results page to dynamically change as text is typed into the search pane...

Comment: Couldn't you just filter the data set your grid is bound to inside the SuggestionRequested handler?